# Positioning Stuff

Tags: html, css, positioning

How do I make a div position coordinates relative to the header? Or should I position everything relative to the bigger wrapper?

Ofc it's something it can be done in several ways but I  thought it'd be best to know how is usually done.

Also, to not be opening another question, and since this can be easily answered,

To position and structure things in the website I use div right. To position a title for a block, should I used a div inside it? like you see below,

```
<div id="LatestQuests">
    <div id="LatestQuestsTitle"> Latest Quests </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#LatestQuests {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 240px;
    height: 190px;
    top: 68px;
    left: 18px;
    border-top-style: outset;
    border-right-style: outset;
    border-bottom-style: outset;
    border-left-style: outset;
    border-top-color: #000;
    border-right-color: #000;
    border-bottom-color: #000;
    border-left-color: #000;
}

#LatestQuestsTitle {
    background: #C0C0C0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what you're asking, but it certainly looks like you should maybe spend a couple hours doing some html/css tutorials...

Comment: `<div>`s are *semantically* meaningless. You should generally use more appropriate html elements when possible. Depending on what you're trying to do, the "title" for a "block" of content could be a `<p>`, a `<header>`, or even a `title="..."` attribute or a pure css `::before`. Relative/absolute positioning is pretty straightforward once you read up on it. There other techniques to do css layout as well.

Comment: also, FYI, your `border` syntax can *probably* be greatly simplified. `border-style: outset` and `border-color: #000` will set these properties on *ALL* sides. You can perhaps even use the `border: 1px outset #000` shorthand to set all `border-` properties at once.

Comment: And setting `display: block` on a `<div>` is generally redundant, as `<div>`s are block-level elements by default

Comment: Yah! Maybe... The way I do it is I put a project in mind and start doing, when I don't know something I google/ask and it has been going well! :D experience>theory. Although they go together; I did find a cool tutorial on positioning, but I only came about it when I actually needed it for a practical reason, http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: Thanks  smaller/'neater' code! :]

Comment: absolutely the "starting with a project" method rather than just reading documentation is a great way to start (>theory). Sorry if I came off as overly critical above. I *do* believe that you will derive some real benefit digging into the Docs and going through a couple tutorials end-to-end now that you have your head around the basics and have a goal in mind. It's pretty easy to hack stuff together when you're starting out, but once a project starts to grow, it will be much easier to build it out further if you're following best practices ;-). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

To position relative to another element, you'd need to set the position of the element you want to place as absolute (position: absolute) and that of the parent element to relative (position: relative).  If there is no relative parent, then body is used.  Think of #LatestQuests as a container holding information about, I assume, Latest Quests.  Then any styling within it should be done in the same manner (so, yes, a div for the title, and probably one for the actual content, etc.).

Comment: "a div for the title, and probably one for the actual content" - So the title div doesn't go inside the div with content? (Because the way I did as you can see was puting the title div inside the content one)

Comment: The way you have it works fine.  All I meant was I've always seen a setup where it's container filled with title and content.  So something like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/zK3ep/.  It just helps with organization in the end.

Comment: Thanks // Why is the top and left lines of the column grey when you set them black? :P (It happened to me too) check it out in your link

Comment: Not sure what you mean - when I look at it, the border is completely black - the only gray part is the background for the title.

Comment: :o just tested it out on chrome and it doesn't happen. I see the grey lines in firefox :P

Comment: Sorry - checked in Firefox, still not seeing it.